# How to Implment feature similar to python's inspect module in rust?

Tags: python, rust

I recently started learning rust and this maybe a very stupid question.

I have a large-ish codebase in python that sort of looks like this (this is all pseudocode as I can't post the original code, it's proprietary):

```
main_package/
   main.py
   transforms/
      __init__.py
      base_transform.py
      class1.py
      class2.py
      ... and so on
```

`base_transform.py` contains a `BaseTransform` parent class with some common methods. And class1.py (any class[x].py) looks something like this:

```
class Class1Transform(BaseTransform):
    id = "class_1"

    def run(data):
      # do some logic
      # return result_value (any python type)
```

Now, in the main.py I use the python's inspect module to get all the classes in the transforms module and then use the `id` field to selectively run the class I want to run. The `data` here is obtained from a database- always a dict.

main.py pseudocode:

```
import transforms
all_classes = inspect.getmembers(transforms, inspect.isclass)
all_classes = list(zip(*all_classes))[1]

code_to_run = sys.argv[2]
for class in all_classes:
    if class.id == code_to_run:
       class().run(get_data())
```

And if you call the main.py with `python main.py class_2`, it will call the `run()` in the `class2Transform` from `class2.py`. You can run multiple `class_x` methods one after the other, and the main.py can read a json file containing the series of `id`s that you want to run one after the other. But I've shown the command line usage for simplicity.

I started learning rust recently and I'm not sure how something like this would be implemented in rust? Considering I have 100+ such classes, divided into 10 sub packages (here I only have shown only one transforms/ package for simplicity). I suppose it's a design question so it would be useful if I can get some pointers on how to even think about a problem like this.

Comment: I would use something like [inventory](https://github.com/dtolnay/inventory).

Comment: But you can also just have an array if they're in the same file.